# Ensuring that threads get (approximately) equal CPU time in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm writing a game in which players write AI agents that compete against one another, on the JVM. Right now the architecture looks like this:

1. A core server module that handles the physics simulations, and takes messages from the players as input to alter the world. The core also determines what the world looks like from the perspective of each of the players, based on various rules (think fog of war).
2. Player modules receive updated versions of the world from the core, process them, and stream messages to the core as inputs based on that processing.

The idea is that the core is compiled along with two player modules, and then the simulation is run producing an output stream that can be played back to generate visualization of the match.

My question is, if each of the players runs on a single Java thread, is it possible to ensure that the two player threads get equal amounts of resources (CPU time, primarily, I think)? Because I don't control the nature of the processing that each AI is doing, it's possible that one of the players might be extremely inefficient but written in such a way that its thread consumes so many resources the other player's AI is resource starved and can't compete fairly.

I get the feeling that this isn't possible without a hard realtime OS, which the JVM isn't even close to being, but if there's even a way to get reasonably close I'd love to explore it.

Comment: Check out [this](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=302) page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Player modules receive updated versions of the world from the core, process them, and stream messages to the
core as inputs based on that processing". This means that player module has a loop inside it which receives update message and sends result messages to the core. Then I would use lightweight actor model, each player being an actor, and all actors use the same ExecutorService. Since activated actors go through the same executor task queue, they got roughly the same access to CPU.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the solution I'm going to go with -- I'm writing the code in Scala anyway so using actors is a no-brainer.

Comment: note that native scala actors are heavyweight (each has a thread attached), so use Akka.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is right that this isn't really possible in Java. Even if you had a real-time OS, someone could still write a very resource intensive AI thread.

There are a couple of approaches you could take to at least help here. First be sure to give the two player module threads the same priority. If you are running on a machine that has more than 2 processors, and you set each of the player module threads to have the highest priority, then theoretically they should both run whenever they have something to do. But if there's nothing to stop the player modules from spawning new threads themselves, then you can't guarantee a player won't do that.

So short answer is no, you can't make these guarantees in java.

Depending on how your simulation works, maybe you can have a concept of "turns". So the simulation instructs player 1 to make a move, then player 2 makes its move, and back and forth ,so they can each only make one "move" at a time. Not sure if this will work in your situation though.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought about turns -- basically update the physics, get input from player A, get input from player B, update the physics again -- but in that case I'd want a way to limit the amount of time that each player got to submit the moves it wanted to make, so that one player wasn't able to spend orders of magnitude more time than another crunching analysis (and thus making much better moves).

Answer (score 0):

If you have any knobs to turn regarding how much work the threads have to do (or just set their priority), you can set up another thread that periodically monitors threads using `ThreadMXBean`s and find their CPU usage using `ThreadInfo.getThreadCpuTime`. You can then compare each players CPU time and react accordingly.
Not sure if this is timely and accurate enough for you, but over time you could balance the CPU usage.
However, splitting the work in packets and using Executors like suggested before should be the better way and more java-like.